# Start network stream to local VLC Media Player software with Javascript

Tags: javascript, vlc

is there a method to start (thanks to a javascript script) the VLC media player software locally by automatically opening the
[network stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70JCd.png)

function, or is it necessary to use a web solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this code:

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var vlcCommand = require('vlc-command');
vlcCommand(function(err, cmd) {
    if (err)
        return console.error('Comando VLC non trovato ' + err);
    cp.execFile(cmd, ['https://server19.streamingaw.online/DDL/ANIME/KanojoMoKanojo/KanojoMoKanojo_Ep_01_SUB_ITA.mp4'], function(err, stdout) {
        if (err)
            return console.error(err);
        console.log(stdout);
    });
});
```

I used two libraries(**child_process** and **vlc-command**) that communicate with the installation of VLC.

```
cp.execFile
```

Starts a network session in VLC.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and explain how this code works, so that other users can understand what it does. Read [answer].